# OpenBSD relayd+httpd vs nginx. Reverse Proxy with tls client certificate

Tags: apache, websocket, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, openbsd

I don't understand. I need reverse proxy with tls client certificate.

- OpenBSD relayd can act as reverse proxy, but it doesn't have tls
  client certificate verification.
- OpenBSD httpd has tls client cert verification, but it can't act as reverse proxy.

I've seen **relayd and TLS client cert verification** http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/relayd-and-TLS-client-cert-verification-td355673.html, and it seems that relayd can support tls client cert verification since Dec '18, anyway, I can't find anything about it in the current (May '19) OpenBSD [relayd(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/relayd.8) man page.

OpenBSD moved the default http server from Nginx to httpd, to be used with relayd, anyway, they haven't achieved the full set of functionality of Nginx (yet).

I'm quite annoyed about this, anyway, I'm almost sure, or at least confident, that they'll achieve it.

I can implement with Nginx the "classic" https server with fast-cgi + https-to-http reverse proxy to websocket applications. But I tested httpd and relayd, and I would like to move to them.

Does anyone here know whether and when OpenBSD will offer reverse proxy + tls client cert verification?

Thank you very much in advance, regards

Comment: can you give us the version of OpenBSD you are currently using? I assume it's OpenBSD 65, or OpenBSD-current, but I am unsure. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is OpenBSD 65